# How to retrieve the correspondence Group ID of a given Group Name in GitLab

Tags: bash, curl, gitlab, gitlab-api

I need to retrieve the correspondence Group ID of a given Group Name in GitLab by using GitLab API.I use following command:

```
GROUP_ID=$(curl -sS --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GIT_TOKEN"\
                -g "$GIT_API/groups?top_level_only=true&per_page=100&page=$page&search="$GROUP_NAME"" | jq -r ".[] .id")
```

But in here, search argument act as a wildcard not gives the exact same matching one.

How do I retrieve the exact same match?